# Twitter Stream API for Direct Message (DM)

Tags: twitter, streaming

I'm reading DM via Twitter GET API and each time I check for them I consume rate limit, even if I don't retrieve any messages.

I've seen it is possible to read DM through Streaming API and I would like to know if this does not consume rate limit or at least is a separate limit before implementing it, as it will take some time to do it. Also, is it fast getting new DM or it has some kind of delay as it is streaming?

So, in short:

1. Does Streaming API not consume my GET API rate limit?
2. Does Streaming API get DM "almost" instantly?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Streaming API limits and REST API limits are completely separate entities. Consuming direct messages via a streaming API doesn't consume any REST API rate limits. And the DMs would arrive within a user stream almost instantaneously, provided that the access token used in the user stream connection had the appropriate permission level associated with it.